# rails multiple user editing the same record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locking, rails-api, optimistic-locking

I have a table in the front end with multiple rows that can be read and edited. Each row has an edit icon that the user will click on, and a dialog will pop up to update the fields in the row. The save button on the dialog will save the fields (call the update API), close the dialog, and reload the table by calling the list API with the same page, filters, and sort order.

To support multiple users reading and editing the same table, I want to lock the row that clicks on the edit icon, and unlock if when the user clicks on save or cancel on the dialog that pops up. To do this, I added a `lock` field to each `row` in the database.

When the user clicks on the edit icon, I send a `lock` API call:

```
        lock_success = false
        message = nil
        row = Row.find(id)
        # (with_lock)
        if row.lock.nil?
          row.lock = @current_user.user_name
          row.save!
          lock_success = true
        end
        # (with_lock_end)
```

When the edit dialog is closed on save or cancel:

```
  Row.update(id, lock: nil)
```

But there could be a case where this follows?

```
  (1) row = Row.find(1)
  (2) row = Row.find(1)
  (1) if row.lock.nil?
  (2) if row.lock.nil?
  (1) row.lock = @current.user_name
  (2) row.lock = @current.user_name
  (1) row.save!
  (2) row.save!
```

If I wrap `row.with_lock` around `(with_lock)` and `(with_lock_end)`, it should solve this problem right?

Lastly, can I use optimistic locking with `lock_version`?.

1. User (1) loads row 1 with version 1.
2. User (2) loads row 1 with version 1.
3. User (1) updates row 1 with version 1, now row 1 is version 2.
4. User (2) updates row 1 with version 1, gets back stale object exception.

Then I won't need to wrap the update calls with `with_lock`? However, how can I keep track of who locked the row via this method?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
lock_obtained = Row.where(id: 1, locked_by: nil).update_all(locked_by: @current_user.user_name, locked_at: Time.zone.now) == 1
# this try to update the row with ID 1 with the current_user's name only if it's not already locked, if the call returns 1 it means that the record was updated so @current_user locked it, if it returns 0 it means the record was already locked by someone else, that's the "== 1" for
```

Now, you'll try to lock the row and know if the row was locked before or succeded in just one line so you won't run into that race condition.

Just a few suggestion:
- I would use an integer with the user id for the locked_by column instead of the name
- I would also save the locked_at timestamp, sounds it could be usedfull
- What do you do if the user closes the tab that locked the row? For this kind of stuff you should use ActionCable so you have can detect if the user got disconnected too.